# Input width differs when there's an icon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build a form using twitter bootstrap and having the input fields' width maximized by using the .input-block-level class.

This works well in this example below, taken from the official site.

- http://pastebin.com/Hi5nTDQq
  [image]

However, if I take the icon example, also from the official site, and use the .input-block-level class on the input element, it doesn't work.

- http://pastebin.com/2KMbyDxT
  [image]

If I apply the .input-block-level class to both *input-prepend* and *input*, it gets wide but a little bit wider than desired.

- http://pastebin.com/uQd3QcBm
  [image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't doing anything wrong. The extra space you have is because of icon. I think You will need to manually make the adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting question, here are the best two solutions I can think of so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/jckTk/

Both have a blank prepend on the password field. One uses the default background and border and on the other you remove the background and right-hand border with some simple CSS.

```
.passwordAddon{
background-color:inherit !important;
border-right:none !important;
}

.password-With-Prepend{
border-left:none !important;
}
```

Good luck!